# Getting started/ welcome screen issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I downloaded VS code and following the getting started videos and figuring out the layout. I managed to get installing the first extension, but when I closed and reopened the app minutes later, I am no longer able to open the getting started page and the welcome screen has changed.

I got this error popup:

```
Unable to open 'vs_code_welcome_page': Unable to resolve resource walkThrough:/c%3A/Program%20Files...
```

I checked `workbench.welcomepage.walkthrough` and was turned **on**.